# Cell Array and function handle

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, function-handle

Look at the below code:

```
for i=1:2
if i == 1
    F{i}= @(x) x(i)+x(i+1);
else
    F{i}= @(x) x(i-1)-x(i)+2;
end
end
```

I wanted to have stored in F something like `F={@(x) x(1)+x(2);@(x) x(1)-x(2)+2;}`. How should I edit my code to achieve this? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a *displaying* issue, rather than a *functional* issue.

Doing this:

```
for i = 1:2
    if i == 1
        F{i}= @(x) x(i)+x(i+1);
    else
        F{i}= @(x) x(i-1)-x(i)+2;
    end
end
```

actually gives the correct results:

```
>> F{1}([1 2 3 4])
ans =
     3    % == x(1)+x(2), i==1

>> F{2}([1 2 3 4])
ans =
     1    % == x(1)-x(2)+2, i==2
```

But the functions are displayed "incorrectly":

```
>> F
F = 
    @(x)x(i)+x(i+1)    @(x)x(i-1)-x(i)+2
```

If you want them to be *displayed* correctly as well, you'll have to get messy:

```
for i=1:2

    if i == 1        
        F{i} = str2func(['@(x)x(' num2str(i) ')+x(' num2str(i+1) ')']);
    else        
        F{i} = str2func(['@(x)x(' num2str(i-1) ')-x(' num2str(i) ')+2']);
    end
end
```

Results:

```
>> F
F = 
    @(x)x(1)+x(2)    @(x)x(1)-x(2)+2
```